# JavaFX Listview - Multiple selections programmacially

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Imagine you have a listview with strings and a List containing strings. I would like to select all the strings inside the listview, that matches the `List<String>`, however, I have tried to use the selectIndices function from the SelectionModel and the correct integers comes out, but it does not select them, only the last one (with grey'ish) colour. I want them all to have a grey'ish colour.

An example would be:

```
Listview: Cat, Dog, Tiger, Gorilla, Monkey
List: Dog & Gorilla.
```

Select Dog & Gorilla inside the Listview. selectionMode is 'MULTIPLE' and the SelectionModel is MultipleSelectionModel.

```
ObservableList<String> names = MainModel.getInstance().getGroupNames();
names.remove(group.getName());

listviewInheritance.setItems(names);

int[] indices = new int[group.getInheritance().size()];
List<String> inheriNames = group.getInheritance();

for(int i = 0; i < inheriNames.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < names.size(); j++) {
        if(inheriNames.get(i).equals(names.get(j))) {
            System.out.println("Inheri: " + inheriNames.get(i) + " | Name: " + names.get(j)); // test purpose
            indices[i] = j;
        }
    }
}

if(indices.length > 0) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indices));
    listviewInheritance.getSelectionModel().selectIndices(-1, indices);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Some code of what you tried might help people in helping you

Comment: Have you set the `selectionMode` to `MULTIPLE`???

Comment: Yes it is. I can select multiple rows with my mouse and control-button, but I want to do it programmacially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little app you can alter. This app selects any `ListView` item that is in the `List`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView lvMain = new ListView();//Create ListView  
        lvMain.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);//Change ListView selection mode to multiple

        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");//ObseravableList that will be used to set the ListView
        lvMain.setItems(items);//Set the ListView's items

        List<String> list = new ArrayList();//List that will hold potential items that are in the ListView
        list.add("Sue");//Add Sue to List
        list.add("Stephan");//Add Stephan to List



        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                //When the Button is pressed, loop through the list checking it's items against the ObservableList's items.
                for(String entry : list)
                {
                    for(String itemEntry : items)
                    {
                        if(entry.equals(itemEntry))//If the items are equal 
                        {
                            lvMain.getSelectionModel().select(itemEntry);//select the item in the ListView
                            break;//If you have duplicates in the ListView remove this line!
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lvMain, btn);


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you want the selected items to appear blue after they are selected, you can just click on the `ListView` or you can add `lvMain.requestFocus();` after the outer `For Loop`.

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't even notice it, but I had another line of code somewhere, so my code did work. Something was overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

The code I was using did work, but I had another line overwriting it. However, the requestFocus() function, Sedrick Jefferson mentioned, do make it blue. Thanks.